# How to turn off data after a certain amount

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tasker, mobile-data, data-monitoring

### How to turn off data after a certain amount

**Aim:** To make my data turn off after it reaches a predefined amount of data to use. **For example**, I am using my portable hotspot to my computer with my phone. After the data used on my phone goes over 100 Mbs of used data the phones then turns the data switch off.

**Problems:** Since my phone is android gingerbread (2.3.6) I don't have the built in data counter that is available in the newer versions of android.

Is this possible with tasker or a play store app?

Any help would be appreciated

---

To anyone wanting an a step-by-step Instructions just leave a comment and I will post a link to a word document, pdf and a txt file (I would have to write them up first)

Comment: To anyone wanting an a step-by-step Instructions just leave a comment and I will post a link to a word document, pdf and a txt file (I would have to write them up first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Video that I Modified:** [Tasker tutorial: Monitor mobile data usage inside Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHknJEYu5oM)

I have only used the task that counts data from this video, If you want a notification that counts used data for a month, the above video is a good solution.

---

**Notes:** Due to unknown reasons, I am unable to turn on USB Tethering, If you Know the answer to this [Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128070/tasker-usb-tethering-context-and-or-task), It would Help a Lot. And Due to this limitation I Have Used a Variable to shows that tether is on, but you will manually have to activate it depending on your circumstances.

**Notes 2:** Due to how it counts data, if you have already used some data on your phone it will change the Data-used variable to the used amount, thus you cant start from a perfect zero. How to combat this;

**1)** You can restart the phone, thus clearing the files that are read that is were the data count has come from.

**OR**

**2)** If you don't want to restart just add the MB's already used onto the data count limit. E.g. It flashes up that you have used 2 Mbs, and you want the data counter to turn off data after 100 MBs, You would have to Put the limit as 102Mbs to be correct

---

### Easy Way

Import the Project Into Tasker: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5mtquWAP3MMjhsd0czeHBjVXc/view?usp=sharing)

[How to Import Tasks/Profiles/Scenes/Projects into Tasker [Video]](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/05/how-to-import-tasksprofilesscenesprojects-into-tasker.html)

---

### Hard Way (Step-by-Step)

Will Add Link to To A  word document, pdf and a txt file (I would have to write them up first) If someone comments that they want the step-by-step Instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Try [My Data Manager - Data Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) app.
It will notify you when you reach your data limit.

Comment: Can you confirm, that this app works for Android 2.3.6? The web page says "Requires Android: Varies with device" so I can't confirm myself. A screenshot or app's official source would would be preferred here.

Comment: 1) I dont see a mention of it turning off data once it reachs it limit, from what i read it just tracks your data and then tells you when the limit is reached 2)Do you know if this uses a lot or RAM (I have limited ram) 3) Can this turn the data off after a predefined amount

Answer (score 0):

You should try "Onavo Count app ", Here are some detailed features check it out :

- Simple setup: Get going in seconds by setting your monthly cap and billing cycle
- You compared with everyone: See how your data use measures up to other people for each app
- Your data life: Understand how you use your data in categories that matter to you like music, maps and videos
- Real-time alerts: Know when you’re approaching your data limit and get an indication of where you stand in your current data cycle with notifications on your phone
- Onavo Extend integration: See how much data you’re saving with Onavo Extend right from the Onavo Count home screen

**Download it from play store:**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid

Helpful Links :

http://www.ekoob.com/how-to-limit-data-usage-on-android-phonestablets-to-avoid-overages-10911/

Comment: Am I able to set a Temp 100 MB Limit and when it reaches it, that the data turns off? I have found a solution using tasker, its not 100% perfect but works as needed. I will upload the Instructions soon

Comment: That's Great @Matt07211